# Trying to get property of non-object using Yii framework

Tags: php, debugging, yii

I am getting a `Trying to get property of non-object` error in Yii. The code used to work before however a co-worker made some changes and now an error is present and I can't for the life of me figure out what is broken.

Here is the stacktrace and error message from applciation.log:

```
2014/07/02 09:39:35 [error] [php] Trying to get property of non-object (/home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/inventory/protected/models/Inventory.php:454)
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(104): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#1 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(48): CInlineAction->runWithParamsInternal()
#2 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CController.php(300): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#3 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(134): InventoryController->runAction()
#4 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/filters/CFilter.php(41): CFilterChain->run()
#5 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CController.php(1144): CAccessControlFilter->filter()
#6 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/filters/CInlineFilter.php(59): InventoryController->filterAccessControl()
#7 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(131): CInlineFilter->filter()
#8 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CController.php(283): CFilterChain->run()
#9 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CController.php(257): InventoryController->runActionWithFilters()
#10 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(277): InventoryController->run()
#11 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(136): CWebApplication->runController()
#12 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/framework/base/CApplication.php(158): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#13 /home/jhvisser/web/inventory/web/inventory/index.php(14): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/inventory/web/inventory/index.php?r=inventory/update&id=14760
```

If you look at the code below this is an error occuring within this function, specifically at the line containing the following: `$attr = $val->attributes;`. The full functions code is below. I am confused as to what the error is here.

```
//get various dropdown fields for UI and validation
public function getDropdown($validate = false)
{
    //make objects
    $feed['equipmentType'] = AuxEquipmentType::model()->findAll();
    $feed['sponsors'] = AuxSponsors::model()->findAll();
    $feed['licences'] = AuxLicences::model()->findAll();
    $feed['groups'] = AuxGroups::model()->findAll();
    $feed['policyEight'] = AuxPolicyEight::model()->findAll();
    $feed['supportClass'] = AuxSupportClass::model()->findAll();
    $feed['special'] = AuxSpecial::model()->findAll();
    $feed['domain'] = AuxDomain::model()->findAll();
    if(!$validate && MAINTAIN_ON)
    {
        $maintain = new Maintain();
        $feed['freeIP'] = $maintain->getFreeIP();
    }
    //get keys of which fields to take and make the string display and value columns with
    $headers = array(
                'sponsors' => array('key' => 'code', 'val' => array('code', 'fullName', 'description')),
                'licences' => array('key' => 'lKey', 'val' => array('licenceName')),
                'groups' => array('key' => 'gr_name', 'val' => array('gr_name')),
                'supportClass' => array('key' => 'value', 'val' => array('value')),
                'special' => array('key' => 'value', 'val' => array('value')),
                'equipmentType' => array('key' => 'value', 'val' => array('value')),
                'domain' => array('key' => 'domain', 'val' => array('domain')),
                'freeIP' => array('key' => 'name', 'val' => array('rang')),
                'policyEight' => array('key' => 'value', 'val' => array('value')),
            );
    $out = array();

    foreach($feed as $field => $value)
    {
        foreach($value as $fld => $val)
        {
            $attr = $val->attributes;  //** THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR **
            if(!$validate)
            {
                if($field == 'freeIP')
                    $attr = $val;
                $option = array();
                foreach($headers[$field]['val'] as $va)
                    $option[] = $attr[$va];
                $out[$field][$attr[$headers[$field]['key']]] = implode(' - ', $option); 
            }
            else
                $out[$field][] = $attr[$headers[$field]['key']];
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($val)` show (put it right before `$attr = $val->attributes`)

Comment: @joseph4tw if I comment out the line `$feed['freeIP'] = $maintain->getFreeIP();` the error of getting property of non-object is gone. This is a new piece of code that was added by a co-worker. Is it likely that this is what is the cause of the error? Dumping the val returns a lot of data.

Comment: It could be the issue. Right after `$feed['freeIP']...` put `var_dump($feed['freeIP']);` and see what it returned. Based on your loops, `$feed['freeIP']` is supposed to have an array in the first subset, then a collection of objects, which it seems that `$feed['freeIP']` doesn't seem to have.

Comment: @joseph4tw Well the output I have looks like the following: http://paste.jhvisser.com/?17b3a88c703b59e4#fT5LIFCUe1rJU7VWFN9jkGrI/Fg0LdtQjCr5lPPlYAE= . I have a feeling this is an incorrectly structured array for how the data is being parsed. There is a line: `if($field == 'freeIP') $attr = $val;`. I'm assuming the coder of this meant to have this check earlier, or had debugging off and the error was being run and ignored?

Comment: @joseph4tw Yep what I thought was correct. Changing the logic slightly fixed this.

Comment: slightly? Are you getting other errors?

Comment: @joseph4tw No, nothing else now.

Comment: cool :) glad it was an easy fix

Comment: @joseph4tw Yeah me too! Wasn't an easy one to find though... at least for me. Thanks for the help! You got me to the right location of the error which was a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

The block of code:

```
if($field == 'freeIP')
    $attr = $val;
```

is in the wrong location as the array is not the same structure as the other $feed elements.

Change the code to the following to correct the error:

```
if($field == 'freeIP')
    $attr = $val;
else 
    $attr = $val->attributes;
```